# The navbar of the page hides under the slide animation .How to prevent this ? i want to show navbar separately on top with animations going as usual

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i have tried keeping the nav in separate div and the slide animation in other it still does not work
this is my code please tell me what to do it just overlaps my navbar. i have tried everything that i can think but still can not do that.

here is the html part

here goes navbar

```
    <ul class="slideshow">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
```

this is the css

```
    body {
      background-color: #000;
    }

    #landing-header {
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 40vh;
    }

    #landing-header h1 {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .slideshow { 
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .slideshow li { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 0;
        animation: imageAnimation 50s linear infinite;
    }


    .slideshow li:nth-child(1) { 
        background-image: url();
    }



    @keyframes imageAnimation { 
      0% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }
      10% {
        opacity: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      30% {
        opacity: 0
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the animation to come out below the navbar? You can explain a little more detailed, what is the effect you want to apply

Answer (score 0):

So I have read what you need but i would like to get more information or a live demo if available.

anyways here's what a simple solution for making a navbar sticky, top and in front of all elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul.slideshow li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10000;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="slideshow">
  <li>MENU</li>
  <li>MENU </li>
  <li>MENU</li>
  <li>MENU </li>
  <li>MENU</li>
</ul>

<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
```

and here is the live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/wgrsvx7k/11/

Comment: i need navbar to be visible on top of that slideshow animation but it does not happen

Comment: @Assassin Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Devel0per95/afwrzh74/

Comment: instead of <ul> on top i want to use a navbar

Comment: I would appreciate if you can send the navbar code with live demo link to check it out :)